# Use MS Bot Framework to integrate with a REST API

Tags: c#, rest, api, botframework

I'm trying to build a bot that would integrate with a REST API. To be more specific, the bot should log into the API, based on credentials provided by the user. Based on certain questions that is asked by the user, the bot should then perform certain actions against the API and report with the results. Something like, 'hey mr. bot, I would like to know my latest sales figures' or 'submit my outstanding events'. The API uses forms authentication, thus after login, the bot would need to send the cookie to the API, otherwise a response of 401 (from API).

Is something like this possible?

[Update]

Since it's unclear as to what I'm asking (down vote), I'll extend my question. I would like to know whether the bot would be able to pass the cookie required by the API to and from the client it's communicating with. Otherwise, with each request to the API, from the bot, the API will see the request as one that is not authorized.

Thanks!

Comment: -1 ... unclear what I'm asking ... really?!
Sometimes I wonder why I even bother asking for help

Comment: Mmmm hard to tell if it's going to work with a cookie... maybe in the WebChat channel, but not sure about other channels (e.g slack/skype). Usually, Auth in bots is handled via OAuth, you get the access token and send the authentication header with the bearer token. Have you tried anything and it's not working or you still haven't gone that path?

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the response! I haven't yet gone that route. I would first need to change my API to use OAuth instead of forms authentication. But you have basically answered my question. Many thanks!

Comment: I will add you more details below; but I'm not saying that cookies don't work, I just don't know.

Comment: Understood, but it feels like I'm not following proper guidelines and practices

Answer (score 2):

I'm not fully sure if this is going to work with cookies. Maybe in the WebChat channel, because of the nature of the channel, may work just fine.

A common pattern I've seen working pretty good with bots is communicating through APIs via OAuth. A good way to implement this is: you send to the user in the bot a link to log in, then the reply will callback to your API where you will basically resume the authentication with the bot and store the access token in the bot state; so you can reuse it on every call.

Since you are using C#, I would recommend checking [AuthBot](https://github.com/MicrosoftDx/AuthBot) ( is a .Net library for Azure Active Directory authentication on bots built via Microsoft Bot Framework).

Also, you can check [AzureBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureBot) to see how the Auth library is being used.